# Axios API response JSON body has "true/false" as string type not boolean

Tags: javascript, axios

I am working on converting angularjs application to react and decided to use axios for API request. 
Everything work fine except some response body with JSON type but the boolean values are string type not boolean. It works fine with angularJs $http but some of endpoints returns like that.

The modules are AngularJs + Typescript 2.9.1 + axios 0.19.0

```
let request = Axios({
    ...requestConfig,
    url: resource, method: 'get', responseType: 'json'
}).then(response => response);
```

and the response body is

```
{
   some: "true"
}
```

but I am excepting

```
{
   some: true
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What is the exact payload that is returned by the API call?

Comment: How does your actual JSON response body look like?

Comment: Both Angular's `$http` and Axios use `JSON.parse()` to deserialise JSON responses so they should both act the same. I suspect you may have a response transformer in your Angular app that is handling these Boolean string values. If you do, you'll need to implement a similar interceptor in Axios or even better, fix the API so it returns the correct types

Comment: `.then(response => response)`  why?

Answer (score 1):

[UPDATE] as [Phil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/283366/phil) pointed out, `Boolean('false')` does not work. I updated the code to something that will work for 'true' and 'false', but a more complex function is needed if you want to cover all possibilities.

---

If the response by the API exactly looks like this:

```
{
  "some": "true"
}
```

Then `axios` is not doing anything wrong. It's dangerous for a library to automagically parse values as they see fit, just look at [how Json.NET handles values that they *think* look like Datetime](https://github.com/JamesNK/Newtonsoft.Json/issues/862).

If the payload returned by the API looks exactly like this:

```
{
  "some" : true
}
```

Then `axios` should parse it as a boolean directly.

What I propose you do, is to *always* parse the value as a boolean, even if it is already one:

```
let request = await Axios({...requestConfig,
      url: resource, method: 'get', responseType: 'json'
    });

let someValue = String(request.data.some) == "true";
```

This will work for `Boolean("true")` as well as `Boolean(true)`.

Comment: FYI, `Boolean("false")` returns `true` so this isn't a solution